# Type is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have create a function like this:

```
type MainProps = { sticky: boolean, refStickyElement: any };
export const MainBlog = ({ sticky, refStickyElement }: MainProps,mposts: TPost[]) => {
...
```

but when I want to use this function at another function I got error:

```
  const {results} = data
  let posts: Array<TPost> = results;
 <MainBlog refStickyElement={element} sticky={isSticky} posts={posts} />
```

error is for `posts={posts}`:

```
Type '{ refStickyElement: MutableRefObject<null>; sticky: boolean; posts: TPost[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MainProps'.
  Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MainProps'.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass `posts` as a prop, you have to add it to the `MainProps` type. React function components **only have one param, which is an object (the props)**.
Therefore, you would have change your `MainProps` type to:

```js
type MainProps = { sticky: boolean, refStickyElement: any, posts: TPost[] };

export const MainBlog = ({ sticky, refStickyElement, posts }: MainProps) => {
  //  ...
}
```